# How to add an additional number to a sample conditionally with the sample command?

Tags: r, replace, sampling

I am fairly new to R, and I am practicing with dice simulations. A game I enjoy uses rolls of six sided dice, and the result of each individual die has some number of successes.

Die Result to Successes

1: 0

2: 0

3: 0

4: 1

5: 2

6: 2, and roll an additional die (this can continue indefinitely)

I would like to be able to roll a number of dice (x), replacing their actual values for the number of successes generated (see above) print the results of each roll, and then print the sum total of the rolls combined for a grand total of successes.

I am trying to program a simulator for these die rolls, but I am stuck in multiple ways.

My loop doesn't seem to accurately affect the sample, so pointing out the proper way to do this would be very helpful. I've tried to iterate this as many ways as I can think of so far and checked on google, but all the replacement information I could find referred to matrices and/or data frames.

Once that's done, I have no idea how to add another interation to a randomly generated sample conditionally (In this case, the number of rolls (x) should increase by +1 for each result of 6) There's nothing currently in the code for it since I didn't know where to start.

Here's what I have so far, I am sure it is very wrong, so thank you for your patience.

```
x <- 10
roll <- sample(1:6, x, replace = TRUE)
for (i in 1:6) {
  if (i <= 3) {
    i <- 0
  } else if (i == 4) {
    i <- 1
  } else if (i == 5) {
    i <- 2
  } else if (i == 6) {
    i <- 2
  }
}
print(roll)
sum(roll)
```

Currently the loop seems to be ignored entirely and the sample just generates normally.

Comment: You dont need a loop to replace the "rolled" integers with the number of successes. You could use a nested `ifelse` or the more parsimonious `dplyr::case_when` (i.e. `dplyr::case_when(roll %in% 1:3 ~ 0, roll %in% 4 ~ 1, roll %in% 5:6 ~ 2)`

Comment: If you don't need the raw 1-6 result and only want the number of successes, `sample` the number of successes directly either with `sample(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2))` or `sample(c(0, 1, 2), prob = c(3, 1, 2))` (fill in the `size` argument too, of course, for the number of rolls)

Answer (score 0):

I would simulate using *recursion* like this:

```
# roll(n) rolls n dice
roll = function(n) {
  # each roll has a 
  #  1/2 probability of 0 successes, 
  #  1/6 chance of 1 success
  #  1/3 chance of 2 successes
  result = sample(
    0:2, size = n, 
    prob = c(3, 1, 2), replace = TRUE
  )
  # we count the 2s in the result
  n_2 = sum(result == 2)
  # each 2 has a 1/2 chance of prompting additional rolls
  n_additional = sum(runif(n_2) > 0.5)
  if(n_additional > 0) {
    # if more rolls are needed, we call this function again
    # and append the result
    result = c(result, roll(n = n_additional))
  }
  # return results of all the rolls
  result
}

## some demonstration (seed set for reproducibility)
set.seed(47)

roll(3)
# [1] 1 0 2 2 0
roll(10)
# [1] 0 2 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 0
length(roll(100))
# [1] 130
## in this instance, rolling 100 dice resulted in a 130 total rolls...
## more than expected, but well within reason

## we could roll 100 dice 100 times and look at how many
## total rolls each instance had:
r100 = replicate(n = 100, length(roll(100)))
summary(r100)
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 110.0   116.0   119.0   119.6   123.0   130.0 

## or similarly look at the number of successes in
## each of 100 simulations of rolling 100 dice
success100 = replicate(n = 100, sum(roll(100)))
summary(success100)
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 74.00   91.75  101.00  100.65  109.00  127.00 

## or look at 100 simulations of rolling 5 dice
success5 = replicate(100, sum(roll(5)))
barplot(table(success5), main = "Successes when rolling 5 dice")
```

[image]

Of course, if you just want the `sum` you can `sum()` the result of `roll` (or replace the last line of the function with `sum(result)` to return the count of successes directly).

This is called *recursion* because the function `roll()`, under certain circumstances (when more dice are needed) will call itself.

Answer (score 0):

It was a nice first attempt, but you are right that there are several things wrong.

The loop from 1 to 6 does not engage with `roll` at all. You might have wanted to do something like:

```
x <- 10
roll <- sample(1:6, x, replace = TRUE)
score <- numeric(x)
for (i in 1:x) {
  if (roll[i] <= 3) {
    score[i] <- 0
  } else if (roll[i] == 4) {
    score[i] <- 1
  } else if (roll[i] == 5) {
    score[i] <- 2
  } else if (roll[i] == 6) {
    score[i] <- 2
  }
}
print(roll)
sum(score)
```

That works if you don't need to re-roll on 6, but you are using more `if` flow-control than you really need. I would store the "outcomes" of each row in a 6-element vector, and then just select the relevant outcome based on the roll. You would implement the conditional re-roll with a `while` loop: basically, if you roll a 6, re-roll (and if you roll a 6 again, re-roll again until you stop rolling 6's):

```
number_of_simulations <- 1000
outcomes <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2)
scores <- numeric(number_of_simulations)
rolls <- vector('list', number_of_simulations)
for (i in seq_len(number_of_simulations)) {
    roll <- sample(6, size = 1)
    scores[i] <- outcomes[roll]
    rolls[[i]] <- roll
    while (roll == 6) {
        roll <- sample(6, size = 1)
        scores[i] <- scores[i] + outcomes[roll]
        rolls[[i]] <- append(rolls[[i]], roll)
    }
}
n_rolls <- sapply(rolls, length)
```

@gregor-thomas Provided a nice solution using recursion, which you might also study to learn more about the power of R. I hope my solution is also helpful!